# For a linear transformation $f \colon V \to W$, $\dim \mathrm{Ker}\, f + \dim \mathrm{Im}\, f = \dim V$

Tags: linear-algebra

I've found in my solution book multiple references to this "dimension theorem" but have been unlucky looking for a more extensive description of this. When does this hold? Are there any other hypothesis needed?

Thanks.

Comment: @Arturo: Thanks for the edit. I was thinking the title looked awful and was looking for the LaTeX code to make it nicer.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem

Comment: No problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Dimension Theorem is often called the "Rank Nullity Theorem", so you may have more luck finding it under that name.

The result holds for **any** linear transformation and vector spaces; it's not even restricted to finite dimensional spaces, so long as your sum is taken to be a sum of cardinals and you assume the Axiom of Choice (so that all vector spaces have bases).

The Dimension Theorem, aka Rank Nullity Theorem, states:

**Dimension Theorem.** *If* $\mathbf{V}$ *and* $\mathbf{W}$ *are* **any** *vector spaces (over the same field), and* $T$ *is* **any** *linear transformation from* $\mathbf{V}$ *to* $\mathbf{W}$, *then* 
$\dim(\mathrm{ker} T) + \dim(\mathrm{Im} T) = \dim(\mathbf{V})$
*where the sum is a sum of cardinals.*

The idea is to start with a basis $\beta$ for $\mathrm{ker} T$, and then extend it to a basis $\beta\cup\gamma$ for all of $\mathbf{V}$. Then you show that the image of $\gamma$ under $T$ is linearly independent: if $\mathbf{v}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{v}_n\in\gamma$ are such that 
$$\alpha_1T(\mathbf{v}_1)+\cdots\alpha_nT(\mathbf{v}_n) = \mathbf{0}$$
in $\mathbf{W}$, then you can rewrite this as
$$T(\alpha_1\mathbf{v}_1+\cdots+\alpha_n\mathbf{v}_n) = \mathbf{0}$$
hence $\alpha_1\mathbf{v}_1+\cdots+\alpha_n\mathbf{v}_n\in\mathrm{ker}(T)$. That means that this linear combination of vectors of $\gamma$ lies in the span of $\beta$, but since $\beta\cup\gamma$ is linearly independent, the only way this can happen is if $\alpha_1\mathbf{v}_1+\cdots+\alpha_n\mathbf{v}_n=\mathbf{0}$; this is a linear combination of vectors in $\gamma$, which is linearly independent, so $\alpha_1=\cdots=\alpha_n=0$. This proves that
$$T(\gamma) = \{T(\mathbf{v})\mid \mathbf{v}\in\gamma\}$$
is a linearly independent subset of $\mathbf{W}$. It is now easy to show that $\mathrm{Im}(T) = \mathrm{span}T(\beta\cup\gamma) = \mathrm{span}(T(\gamma))$, so that $\dim(\mathrm{Im}(T)) = |\gamma|$. So you have that
$$\dim\mathbf{V} = |\beta\cup\gamma| = |\beta|+|\gamma| = \dim(\mathrm{ker}\; T) + \dim(\mathrm{Im}\; T),$$
as desired.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no other hypothesis needed. In particular, the dimension of $V$ may be infinite.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank-nullity_theorem